# Unreal Engine: How can I create UStaticMeshComponent in a loop?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am trying to create multiple `UStaticMeshComponent` by using for loop but Unreal Engine keeps triggering breakpoint on `CreateDefaultSubobject` in `Object.h`(Not in my code, it's from UE4 core API). When I'm creating a single component it's working fine. I am pretty new to UnrealEngine and C++ so I might be doing something dumb but please be easy on that:)

Thank you so much for your help.

**Header**

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "FlowSphere.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class CPP_PRACTICE_3_API AFlowSphere : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public: 
    // Sets default values for this actor's properties
    AFlowSphere();

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public: 
    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

private:
    //UPROPERTY()
    //TArray<UStaticMeshComponent*> StaticMeshComponents;

    UStaticMeshComponent* test;

};
```

**C++**

```
#include "FlowSphere.h"

// Sets default values
AFlowSphere::AFlowSphere()
{
    int32 amount = 100;

    RootComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<USceneComponent>("SceneComponent");

    for (int32 i = 0; i < amount; i++) {

        //WHEN I INCLUDE THE LINE BELOW, UE4 START MAKING BREAKPOINT
        UStaticMeshComponent* item = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("Sphere"));
        item.AttachTo(this->RootComponent);

    }

    //THIS WORKS FINE
    this->test = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("HELLO")); 
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void AFlowSphere::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

}

// Called every frame
void AFlowSphere::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

}
```

**Where it triggering breakpoint on the `Object.h` from UE4 API**

```
    /**
    * Create a component or subobject
    * @param    TReturnType                 class of return type, all overrides must be of this type
    * @param    SubobjectName               name of the new component
    * @param    bTransient                  true if the component is being assigned to a transient property. This does not make the component itself transient, but does stop it from inheriting parent defaults
    */
    template<class TReturnType>
    TReturnType* CreateDefaultSubobject(FName SubobjectName, bool bTransient = false)
    {
        UClass* ReturnType = TReturnType::StaticClass();
        return static_cast<TReturnType*>(CreateDefaultSubobject(SubobjectName, ReturnType, ReturnType, /*bIsRequired =*/ true, /*bIsAbstract =*/ false, bTransient));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You used the same name for two different calls to CreateDefaultSubobject.

I ran your code in a new UE4 C++ project and got the following error message:

> Fatal error:
>   [File:D:\Build++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\UObjectGlobals.cpp]
>   [Line: 3755] Default subobject StaticMeshComponent Sphere already
>   exists for FlowSphere /Script/MyProject.Default__FlowSphere.

Also, the code you posted didn't compile.

```
item.AttachTo(this->RootComponent);
```

should have been:

```
item->AttachTo(this->RootComponent);
```

and you also needed to include "Components/StaticMeshComponent.h". Here is the corrected code:

```
#include "FlowSphere.h"
#include "Components/StaticMeshComponent.h"

// Sets default values
AFlowSphere::AFlowSphere()
{
    int32 amount = 100;

    RootComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<USceneComponent>("SceneComponent");

    for (int32 i = 0; i < amount; i++) {

        FName name = *FString::Printf(TEXT("Sphere %i"), i);
        UStaticMeshComponent* item = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(name);
        item->AttachTo(this->RootComponent);

    }

    this->test = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("HELLO"));
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I had to do the same thing recently and ran into a lot of issues but the two major things to fix are:

1. use UInstancedStaticMesh instead of UStaticMesh.
2. add a property to your static mesh.

Below is the correct code.

```
#include "FlowSphere.h"
#include "Components/StaticMeshComponent.h"
#include "UObject/ConstructorHelpers.h"

// Sets default values
AFlowSphere::AFlowSphere()
{
    int32 amount = 100;

    RootComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<USceneComponent>("SceneComponent");

    for (int32 i = 0; i < amount; i++) {

        FName name = *FString::Printf(TEXT("Sphere %i"), i);
        FName c_name = *FString::Printf(TEXT("ChildSceneComponent %i"), i);

        UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
            USceneComponent* ChildSceneComponent
            = CreateDefaultSubobject<USceneComponent>(c_name);

        // instead of the regular static mesh, create and instance static mesh object with name assigned
        UInstancedStaticMeshComponent* item = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(name);
        item->RegisterComponent();

        // assign property to mesh if not you'll get a static mesh null property error like i did 
        auto MeshAsset = ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder<UStaticMesh>(TEXT("StaticMesh'/Engine/BasicShapes/Sphere.Sphere'"));

        if (MeshAsset.Object != nullptr)
        {
            item->SetStaticMesh(MeshAsset.Object);
        }
        item->SetFlags(RF_Transactional);

        // add instance to actor level
        this->AddInstanceComponent(item);

        // make the scene component for the mesh to be visible
        RootComponent = Root;

        // attach mesh to the scene component of the actor in form of a Hierarchy

        item->AttachToComponent(ChildSceneComponent, FAttachmentTransformRules::KeepWorldTransform, m_name);
        ChildSceneComponent->AttachToComponent(Root, FAttachmentTransformRules::KeepWorldTransform, c_name);

        // set mesh transform based on the ith position
        FTransform t(FVector(250 * i, i, i));

        // activate the new copy of the mesh
        Mesh->AddInstance(t);

        // Offset and scale the child scene from the root scene as a precaution
        ChildSceneComponent->SetRelativeTransform(
            FTransform(FRotator(0, 0, 0),
                FVector(250 * i, i, i),
                FVector(0.1f))
        );


    }


    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

}
```